# Garden Fi mobile app - dark theme styling issue on Android with select html elements

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Running into a styling issue when in the Garden Fi mobile app on seemingly any Android device. When using dark theming within the phone settings, html select elements embedded within our plugin code can be clicked, but the modal that pops up showing the options menu on Android shows as a white background with white text, making the options invisible.

The embedded code utilizes dark theming, and is showing that theming correctly, but the options menu doesn't seem to recognize that the phone is using a dark theme. Seems to look and work as intended on browser on Android, or any environment on iOS. For reference, our code is basic html, css, javascript.

I have attempted multiple styling changes to the select and option elements within our code, such as background-color and color updates to change background/font color. These changes don't have any effect on the way Android displays its options popup menu

Has anybody else run into this issue? Considering potential workarounds, would love suggestions.

Thank you for your help!

[mobile app on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKtv.png)
[mobile browser on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGfo8.png)

[android webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmCJ0.png)

Comment: if possible it would be great if you could include a link to sample code that demonstrates the issue. It's especially great if you're able to reproduce the problem in our [Simple Plugin Example](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example).

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. thanks for the suggestion! I've done my best to recreate the issue in your example here - https://github.com/nickWinters51824/test-plugin . I've embedded one of our components as well a basic select element that may reproduce the problem. I'm unable to test locally on an android device currently

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample code, that should hopefully be helpful when I work with Engineering on this topic.

Comment: Has anyone from your company verified that this is indeed an issue on an actual Android device? (Just want to make sure that this isn't a weird artifact of BrowserStack or similar.)

Comment: Yep, I just had a team member test again on their Google Pixel 6a, Android v13, and are seeing the same issue. I have also seen the issue on an actual Android phone, but unsure of the device details at this time.

Comment: Okay, that's useful info. Thank you.

Comment: If a question requires code to be answerable, that code must be provided as an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like the sample code _is_ a minimal, reproducible example though.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you able to get that webview content to properly render the `select` and `option` HTML elements in dark mode in a _different_ Android app (i.e. one that _isn't_ Banno)? That might narrow things down a bit.

Comment: Hey Jaime, no unfortunately Banno is the only Android app to my knowledge that we embed our components in. I'm messing around with Android Studio to see if I can make an app and test there, but not having a ton of luck thus far (I'm not an Android dev)

Comment: I was able to load up one of our components an a webview in an android app in android studio, and am seeing the styles shown correctly, but I'm not sure if that's a similar environment to Banno or not. I've added a pic of this in the description above titled 'android webview'

Comment: Super helpful. As it turns out, webviews in the Android SDK use a _native_ dialog for `select` / `option` elements so that exposed a problem in the Banno Mobile app for Android and how it handles dark mode for those. Engineering has a fix in mind.

Comment: @Nick version `3.2` of the Android app has shipped and is making its way across various customers. Please try again with that version as there are a couple of fixes which should address this very issue.